# Abstract class VS Enumerations (general OOP)

Tags: oop

I really can't find how to decide which option is the best. I have a class "Product" which has a "RecommendedAge" for the animal intended to be fed, among other attributes.

Please note that I just want the different values from RecommendedAge for each species, I don't care about their numerical equivalent (what would be represented with a Discriminated Union, but I can't use that due to ORM issues).

As "RecommendedAge" possible values differ depending on the type of Animal de Product targets, I don't know which of the following (or any other) approach is the best (all pseudocode):

```
Class Product {
    Id id;
    String name;
    RecommendedAge recommendedAge;
}

AbstractClass RecommendedAge {
}

Class DogRecommendedAge : RecommendedAge {
    readonly const Int Big;
    readonly const Int Small;
}

Class CatRecommendedAge : RecommendedAge {
    readonly const Int Medium;
    readonly const Int Tiny;
}
```

Or something like:

```
AbstractClass Product {
    Id id;
    String name;
}

Enum DogRecommendedAge {
    Big = 0;
    Small = 1;
}

Enum CatRecommendedAge {
    Medium = 0;
    Tiny= 1;
}

Class DogProduct : Product {
    DogRecommendedAge dogRecommendedAge;
}

Class CatProduct : Product {
    CatRecommendedAge catRecommendedAge;
}
```

This may be a very silly one, but I'm stuck. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

What about just storing recommended ages during runtime instead of at compile time? In your pseudo:

```
class RecommendedAges { 
  readonly const RecommendedAge dog = new RecommendedAge(2, 5); // example value
  readonly const RecommendedAge cat = new RecommendedAge(3, 4); // example value 
}

Class Product {
    Id id;
    String name;
    RecommendedAge recommendedAge;
}

Product p = new Product(1, 'dog food', RecommendedAges.dog);
```